# What metric to use to define model performance when the change in dependent variable is very small?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, regression

I have built a regression model with 5 inputs and 1 output.

I am using r2_score as a metric to evaluate my model performance.

```
#calculate r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
score_test = r2_score(y_pred,y_test)
```

Variations in my output variable is very small. My output variable look like:

```
102.23003
102.23007
102.22958
102.22858
102.22691
102.2246
102.22179
102.21818
102.21372
102.20828
102.20172
102.193886
102.18463
102.1738
102.160164
102.14266
```

Distribution of my dependent variable
[image]

Variations are only in the second decimal level.

When I use r2_score as an accuracy metric , the r2_score comes out to be 99%.

So my question is, is r2_score a correct metric in such cases where the variation in dependent variable is so small?

Does this 99% r2_score imply my model is performing very well?

Comment: `r2` measures how far off the average square error **relative** to the variation. So in a way, it is independent from the scale of the data and its variation. And yes, 99% looks pretty good to me.

Comment: The posted data fits a generalized Pareto distribution very well, but a Gaussian normal distribution very poorly. This would indicate to me that the model is insufficient - except for the fact that the R-squared value is so good that this may not be of practical significance.

Comment: Thanks @JamesPhillips !! Any idea which algorithm and performance metrics to be used with response distributions of pareto type? I have used an ANN model and r2_score as a metric.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/418383/finding-the-best-prediction-model-for-data-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you ask about algorithm and performance metrics. Here is what I did: I pasted your data into my online open source statistical distributions fitter at http://zunzun.com/StatisticalDistributions/1/ and hit the Submit button. It fit the data to the 90+ continuous statistical distributions in scipy.stats, and the generalized Pareto distribution was near the top of the results, yielding:

```
Generalized Pareto distribution
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genpareto.html

Fit Statistics for 16 data points:
    Negative Two Log Likelihood = -1.3852573661570938E+02
    AIC = -1.3252573661570938E+02
    AICc (Burnham and Anderson) = -1.3052573661570938E+02


Parameters:
    c = -3.7800889226684840E+00
    location = 1.0213689198388039E+02
    scale = 3.5222118656995849E-01
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I understand that its following a pareto distribuiton, but how to fit a model between the 5 input parameters and the output.

Comment: Imagine that you had a nearly perfect model, where the 5 inputs almost perfectly modeled the response variable. Since the model was a nearly perfect fit, the *model output* would also follow a Pareto distribution for those same inputs. That model could have been created by OLS regression, where the *fitting error* between model predictions and the response variable is normally distributed. I suggest reviewing scatterplots of all 5 input variables versus the response variable to determine of any obvious data transformation, such as log or exp, might help in the regression.